# USB 2.0 support on legacy motherboard

Tags: windows-xp, usb, motherboard

One of the machines I've is a 10 year old one. I can't discard it due to some sentiment (Mom). Legacy board: Mercury 810e / on board USB 1.1

**Problem**: USB 2.0 ALi PCI card doesn't work as it supposed to (hi-speed) - only in 1.1

**Observation**: Every time I connnect any device, say iPod, I see *hi-speed USB missing on this PC*...some message like this).

How to know what is the problem:

1. Does board supports it?
2. Board damage?
3. BIOS limitation?
4. What else?

Comment: Have you installed the driver for the USB card? The motherboard and BIOS does not affect PCI devices much after NT kernel is loaded. In some older computers the PCI bus may run at the FSB frequency, so you could have a bandwidth problem. However, this is really very rare. I cannot find the detailed technical spec on the board... You can check if you have the options to change PCI frequency in BIOS.

Comment: @billc.cn I'll explain what I did. 1) Installed the driver. 2) Disabled on board USB 1.1 3) Disabled Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller in USB Host Controllers from Device Manager. 4) I can see ALi PCI  USB driver entries (2) in USB Host Controllers. NOTE: FSB is 133 MHz for 810e MOBO. Same matching SD RAM of 512 MB (2 slots). NO option to change PCI Frequency in BIOS. Even after doing all this, USB doesn't work in 2.0 mode. Some where I read the old BIOS doesn't support USB 2.0 spec? Is this true? I don't know about this matter.

Comment: In light of your latest questions, this is a good question.